# Iterate Rails Array of Objects in React-Native

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to iterate an Array of Objects (retrieved from an ActiveRecord query) in a react-native app to render inside a table.

ActiveRecord query

```
def list
    render json: Client.select('name, created_at, id').order('created_at DESC')
  end
```

And this is how i am obtaining the data from the API (react):

```
getStatus() {
 fetch(global.api_clients, {
   headers: {
     Accept: 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Authorization': 'Token token=' + global.token,
   },
 })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    this.setState({
      clients: responseJson
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

Query output

```
Array [
  Object {
    "created_at": "2019-05-08T11:33:06.573Z",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Francesco",
  },
]
```

Rendering

```
render() {
    const state = this.state;
    const listItems = state.clients.map((link) =>
      <Row data={link.name} textStyle={styles.text}/>
    );

    console.log(this.state.clients);

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff'}}>
          <Row data={state.tableHead} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.text}/>
          {listItems}
        </Table>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

undefined is not a function (near '...data.map...')

Comment: Have you tried initializing this.state.clients to an empty array? It's likely that the render function is being called before the response has returned from the api, if you have nothing define for state.clients js will throw an error

Comment: You need to initialize it with an empty array. Because first-time page load it is not defined.

Comment: I'm declaring state.clients as an empty array inside constructor, then i call getStatus and finally i i try to render. console.log(state.clients) renders correctly the data, but i do not know how to iterate it correctly, accessing object keys too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.
Error was in Row data, since it pretends an array.
Solved this way:

```
<Row data={[link.name, link.id, link.name]} textStyle={styles.text}/>
```